# Use meta_query to display events by date in custom field

Tags: php, wordpress, post, meta

I'm working on a template for a specific category archive of the custom post type event.

I need to make a query that shows future and ongoing events, ordering by a date in custom field.

```
<?php
$termName = get_queried_object()->name;
$termSlug = get_queried_object()->slug;
$event1 = current_time('Y-m-d');

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'event',
    'event-categories' => $termSlug,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation'    => 'OR',
        array(
            'relation'    => 'AND',

        array(

            'key' => '_event_start_date',
            'value' => $event1,
            'compare' => '>=',
            'type' => 'DATE',

        ),


        array(

            'key' => '_event_end_date',
            'value' => $event1,
            'compare' => '>=',
            'type' => 'DATE',

        )
        ),
        array(
            'key' =>  $event1,
            'value' => array('_event_start_date','_event_start_date'),
            'type' => 'DATE',
            'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
        )

    ),

     'orderby' => '_event_start_date',
 );
$events = new WP_Query($args);
echo $events->post_count   ;
?>
```

The results is only the future events but no ongoing events.

Whant's wrong?